# Why i am getting extra records in pandas merge with outer join

Tags: python, pandas

It would be great if someone help me to understand what could be the below issue.

1. 5th Jan orders data(dataframe name=ord_5) and record count is 3976195.
2. 6th Jan orders data (dataframe name=ord_6) and record count is 3999418.

when I did outer join with pandas merge getting below count of records for 3 merge categories.

```
pd.merge(ord_5, ord_6, how='outer', indicator=True)
```

1. both:- 3946558
2. left only:- 29667
3. right only:- 52890

now my expectation is len(ord_5) == count(both + left only) and len(ord_6) == count(both + right only). Unfortunately I am getting 30 records gap at record count level. Any specific reason ?
please same script working fine with sample data no records count miss match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try to find out which ones are missing ? here's the idea.

```
 ord_5['test']= 1 
 ord_6['tett']=1
 x = (df1['test'] +df2['test']).dropna(axis=0)
 print(x[x['test']!=2)
```

and then repeat same for ord6-ord5

Comment: your trick worked and those extra rows belongs to "NaN". Now I used drop na. So i am good. Thanks for your direction leon.